# PHP-Devel Dependency issues with PHP 5.3.23

Tags: php

I am trying to install php-devel and I get this issue.

I have PHP Installed, I have tried Googling and other things but they don't work.

This is my environment:

PHP -version

```
PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jun  9 2013 12:23:50)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

OS version:
cat /etc/redhat-release

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.5 (Tikanga)


[root@box html]# yum install php-devel
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-devel.x86_64 0:5.1.6-27.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5 for package: php-devel
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5.x86_64 from workstation has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: php = 5.1.6-27.el5 is needed by package php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5.x86_64 (workstation)

Packages skipped because of dependency problems:
    php-devel-5.1.6-27.el5.x86_64 from workstation
```

Comment: `yum install php` first..

Comment: I have PHP installed already! I am trying to do this later. Do you still want me to try this out?

Comment: yum install php
Setting up Install Process
Package matching php-5.1.6-27.el5.x86_64 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do

Comment: Why so many downvotes?

Comment: I am not sure. but this is definitely not the way I would want to be treated if someone is new to a place. I tried to give as much as possible. Sadly few eople are so pessimistic that they see flaws in everything!

Comment: This is off-topic, because it *is not* a programming problem. It's a package manager discrepancy. Probably architecture related. It becomes a programming problem only if you download PHPs source from git/svn and get a compiling problem or else.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions in the link.

http://www.howtoforge.com/quick-n-easy-lamp-server-centos-rhel

or if you are done installing and configuring your MYSQL and Web Server just copy the below:

```
yum install php php-mysql php-common php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-devel php-xml
```

Download and install the following RPM

```
http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/21966196/dir/centos_other/com/php-devel-5.3.26-1.w5.x86_64.rpm.html
```

Problem: You have php 5.3.26 and you are trying to install php-devel 5.1

Check the RPM provided. I suppose it should go with Red Hat 5.5. If it doesn't either you need to find the appropriate RPM of php-devel 5.3.26 for your system (try yum install php53-devel) or Downgrade your php to version 5.1. Or update your repos and then you can fetch the latest version of both php and php-devel using yum

OK I suppose this should work.

**Step 1:** Remove the current version of php

```
yum erase php
```

**Step 2:** Download and install the following RPM

```
http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/remi/enterprise/5/x86_64/php-5.4.16-1.el5.remi.x86_64.html
```

**Step 3:** Download and Install this RPM

```
http://rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/remi/enterprise/5/x86_64/php-devel-5.4.15-1.el5.remi.x86_64.html
```

Comment: But I already have PHP, HTTPD and everything up and running. I Just need the php-devel package and using yum install php-devel does not work!

Comment: please paste the output of the following 

php --version

Comment: PHP -version


PHP 5.3.26 (cli) (built: Jun  9 2013 12:23:50)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies


cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.5 (Tikanga)

Comment: Thank you for your post. I suppose it's for CentOS. Could you give me the Redhat version? Also, I'm trying to do this.

rpm -Uvh <link> I suppose it's alright?

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your reply. The php-devel link does not work (The FTP link is down).Could you provide me with alternative compatible version if possible? I did a lot of Google but never found this package on the internet.Thanks!

Comment: And also, can I use this package? http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/5/remi/x86_64/php-devel-5.4.16-1.el5.remi.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you have PHP 5.3 installed on your machine, but the default php-devel package that `yum` tries to install is for PHP 5.1, which causes the conflict.  You can instead try to install the php-devel meant for PHP 5.3.  In some cases, this can be done with:

```
yum install php53-devel
```

Comment: I get this output

yum install php53 php53-devel
Setting up Install Process
No package php53 available.
No package php53-devel available.
Nothing to do